# ruby callback: Can an instantiated object call a method in its parent scope?

Tags: ruby, callback

Can an instantiated object call a method in its parent scope?

To illustrate my question, here's a piece of code:
I have a class like this

```
class Tdd
  def initialize
    @ui = Ui.new
    @ui.event_loop
  end

  def process_invoices
  end
end
```

For your information, the event_loop() method detects keys pressed
using a getch() method. If the key pressed was "p" then the process_invoices() method of the parent object (Tdd class) should be executed by the the code in the event_loop method.

How to make this happen? I'm looking for something like

```
self.superclass.process_invoices()
```

to be doable inside the event_loop() method.

Comment: Well, for Ruby, when I think parent scope, I think about inheritance. So `class Tdd < Ui` and it inherits all its methods. 
In the example you provided, instance variable `@ui` inside each instance object of Tdd will be able to access the methods in class Ui because you created that object inside each instance of Tdd. So, in the case of `@ui`, it can use any methods declared in class Ui.

Comment: In my code there is no class Tdd < Ui relationship. And they are fundamentally different classes so i don't want to create that < relationship

Comment: To Philip's question, when you write 'self.superclass', which class do you think of as the superclass?